# Is there a way to disable datadog's log collection for a development environment?

Tags: datadog

I've tried searching on [datadog's docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/) but I have not found any information regarding whether it is possible to deactivate log sending on certain envs (development for ex), therefore I'm forced to create a "fake logger" for dev env and only create a datadog logger for the other envs, I'd appreciate to know if it is possible to configure that scenario in order to avoid having to implement 2 different loggers.

I'm using @datadog/browser-logs for typescript, v2.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the config for how to disable sending logs to Datadog, and only log to console. If you want to disable logs entirely, use `silent`

```
datadogLogs.logger.setHandler('console')
```

https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/javascript/#change-the-destination

Answer (score 0):

If you app is deployed to different environments, ideally you already have the deploy process pass a variable in which indicates which environment it is:
'production' 'stage' 'sandbox' etc,

If not add that, then you can have that var set to 'local' when running locally, using .env file, and use the value of that variable to skip the code the initialises datadog.logger in you app.